# Make one column of cells determine row height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with two columns, and I want the height of each row to be determined by the height of the content in the right column, so that cells in the left column will tend to get cut off vertically.

Can I do this in CSS? I've tried setting `max-height=100%` on the left `td`, as well as using a `div` inside the left `td` and setting `max-height=100%` on that instead. But the rows still get sized to fit whichever cell is biggest, rather than ignoring the size of the left one.

Comment: Please add a sample of your html and css, it will be much easier to assist you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the div to `position:absolute` with `overflow:hidden` etc, and set some `width` on the `td` to prevent it from collapsing with the only absolute div inside.

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
}
td {
  width: 50%;
}
td:first-child {
  position: relative;
}
td:first-child  > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting the width of the cells as you did is also key.